# hide selected date using php

Tags: php, sql, list

I am building a booking system by which the user selects a date from a list of dates available which is then submitted to the database.  I would like for this date to be removed or hidden in the list, when the user submits his selection so as the same date cannot be selected more than once.

Small explanation of what I want to be displayed:
if dates submitted are: 20.4.2015, 21.4.2015, 25.4.2015, and 28.4.2015

```
in database</br>
in database</br>
<option value='23.4.2015'>23.04.2015</option>
<option value='24.4.2015'>24.04.2015</option>
in database</br>
<option value='26.4.2015'>26.04.2015</option>
<option value='27.4.2015'>27.04.2015</option>
in database</br>
```

This is my php code:

```
 $begin = new DateTime('today');
 $end = new DateTime('today+91day');

 $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
 $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

 foreach ($period as $date) {
   $db_link = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or    die('Cannot connect');
    mysql_select_db("database",$db_link) or die('Cannot select the DB');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM reservations";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$db_link) or die('cannot get results!');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ( $date->format("j.n.Y") != $row['date_of_reservation']) {
            echo "<option value='". $date->format("j.n.Y"). "'>". $date->format("d.m.Y")."</option>\n"; 
        }
        else {
            echo "in database";
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result I'm getting from the code above:

```
in database - </br>
<option value='21.4.2015'>21.04.2015</option>
<option value='21.4.2015'>21.04.2015</option>
<option value='21.4.2015'>21.04.2015</option>
<option value='22.4.2015'>22.04.2015</option>
in database - </br>
<option value='22.4.2015'>22.04.2015</option>
<option value='22.4.2015'>22.04.2015</option>
<option value='23.4.2015'>23.04.2015</option>
<option value='23.4.2015'>23.04.2015</option>
in database - </br>
<option value='23.4.2015'>23.04.2015</option>
<option value='24.4.2015'>24.04.2015</option>
<option value='24.4.2015'>24.04.2015</option>
<option value='24.4.2015'>24.04.2015</option>
in database - </br>
```

Comment: In what format do you keep your date in the DB? Plus you better use $interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); because your code clearly repeats one date multiple times.

Comment: a `<select>` can only contain `<option>`. YOu can't just dump raw text into a select and expect it to render properly...

Comment: Change your sql query `SELECT DISTINCT date_of_reservation FROM reservations;`

Comment: Please mention DB Date format , in which format you stored and which format you want?

Comment: The date format in sql is varchar(10) - which gives the (j.m.Y format)

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed. Here is the solution my friend came up with:

```
<?php

$begin = new DateTIme('today');
$end = new DateTime('today+90day');
$flag = false;

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

$db_link = mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password3") or    die('Cannot connect');
mysql_select_db("uirqxukx_bookings",$db_link) or die('Cannot select the DB');
$query = "SELECT * FROM reservations";
$result = mysql_query($query,$db_link) or die('cannot get results!');   
foreach ($period as $date) {
$result = mysql_query($query,$db_link) or die('cannot get results!');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row['date_of_reservation'] == $date->format("j.n.Y") &&     $row['reservationType'] == "FULLDAY")
    {
        echo "";
        $flag = true;
    }
}
if ($flag == false)
{
    echo "<option value='". $date->format("j.n.Y"). "'>". $date->format("d.m.Y")."</option>\n";
    $flag = false;
}
$flag = false;
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you just want them not to show up in the list of options, remove the

```
echo "in database"
```

line.  You also probably want to wrap your  outputs inside a named  element (outside your while loop - open the  before the loop and close the  after it)

Comment: The in database line is for testing purposes, I'd remove it once it works

Comment: have you actually viewed the results of your query? how many rows are there being returred for each date? under each date?

Comment: Yes I'm  getting all the results of the query using echo $row['date_of_reservation']

Comment: and how many rows are there in the query results for each date?